# How can I manage to have an auto-insert timestamp value in my table in SQL-Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, timestamp

Im working on a project. My project contains a c# program and an attached database. I need to have a column to record the time, when data is inserted into my table.

My goal is to be able to report my data in different time intervals.

what I have already tried: I have included a timestamp column in my table. I thought adding a timestamp column will automaticly do the job for me. but its not recording time by itself I guess I have to enter time to it from a source.

I have searched my problem in google but there was not any how-to question. all questions were about the differences between time data types.

Comment: You should tag the database you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to either use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
[Microsoft suggestion for having a Timestamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timestamp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

which actually I didn't use it myself in my project.

What I did do was to have a label and a timer in my C# program. I would trigger the timer with a click on a button and stop it somewhere in my program and store the time value in a variable (let's call it Timevariable). Then when I'm entering other information in my database, I would use that variable to store the time which I chose it to be a timestamp in my database with the following code:

```
sqlcon.Open();

SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("AddTime", sqlcon);
sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otherInformation",source of that Information);
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTimeStamp", Timevariable);

sqlcon.Open();
```

I'm using a stored procedure here.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is have a column with nvarchar(15) type and set it to

```
DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

in c# .

So, you can make strings you want with the date time like : yyyy/MM/dd or MM/yyyy/dd

maybe this url will help you :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2